# fb messenger chatbot not working in WebView err unknown_url_scheme error

Tags: android-studio, webview, facebook-messenger-bot

I am creating a webview app. all is ok but when I try to click the messenger icon and try to connect then nothing happened. messenger is not work. but it works fine on the browser. can anyone help me with that? I am trying a lot of methods no one is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(url.startsWith("intent:"))
  {
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.me/***********"));
       startActivity(i);
       return true;
  }
```

You are not able to load the intent link which redirects to the messenger. Instead use the messenging url of your page or id whenever you get the intent link. You can find your facebook page link as in the screenshot shown below [Settings -> Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQDZ0.png).